# How to set the "task" or "application" name for a python script with a GTK - UI?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygobject

Is it possible to set the "application name" (the name which is displayed in the OS's task switcher etc.) for a GTK3 window created with [PyGObject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Currently it always shows the scripts name, e.g. `hello_world.py`. If so, how?

I also tried to create a `.desktop` file for the script and launched that, but that didn't help either.

**My System:** Python 3.7, PyGObject 3.40.0, Ubuntu 20.10

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Execute the [official example](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for a GTK application with PyGObject:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Hello World")
window.show()
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

2. With the application running, press e.g. `Super`+`Tab` and see something like:
   [image: screenshot]

(Sorry for the photo, somehow I wasn't able to screenshot the task-switcher on Wayland. It's like a ghost!)

Comment: I would like to know a solution for this problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

This may work depending on how the task switcher is implemented:

`GLib.set_application_name("My app name")`

It doesn't work all places in my Linux Mint system. The System Monitor doesn't reflect the app name, for instance.

Maybe I can find some info on this going forward.